# Google Chat (Hangouts) not showing company users in search?

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts

When logged into Gmail and using Chat, if I have a coworker named Bob Example and I started typing Bob in the search in the lower left for chat (or type Bob and click the magnifying glass,) Bob Example appears as a contact to chat with. Now there are no results.

If I start typing Bob's email address, he appears as a result to start a chat with.

It also seems that Bob *will* show up if he was a recently contacted chat connection.

If I go into Gmail settings, the menu for Chat shows only Chat: On/Off, so I suspect it's using Hangouts chat (in Chrome) rather than the old Gchat because before there were several settings in that menu, not just on/off.

How do I get Hangouts Chat to use the company directory to find people in Chat, rather than just recent contacts?

Comment: Is the domain directory enabled? One way to know if it's enabled is going to http://contacts.google.com and click on  Directory on the left panel, if a list of people is shown then it's enabled.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be directory enabled when I look in that setting.